# Why is RemoteFileTemplate ignoring the value set in setFileNameExpression?

Tags: java, spring, expression, filenames, spring-integration

Using Spring-integration 4.1.1.RELEASE to upload files in message payloads to remote sFtp shares. I'm using an sFtpRemoteFileTemplate initialized like this:

```
Expression remoteDirectoryExpression = new  LiteralExpression("si.sftp.sample");
SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression fileNameExpression = new LiteralExpression("foo.txt");

template = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sessionFactory);
template.setCharset("UTF-8");
template.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
template.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
template.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(remoteDirectoryExpression);
template.setFileNameExpression(fileNameExpression);
template.setTemporaryFileSuffix(".writing");
template.setUseTemporaryFileName(true);
template.afterPropertiesSet();
```

However, whatever literal I place in the fileNameExpression is ignored, and the uploaded file will always be named **the same as the original file**. The result is always the same as if it were:

```
Expression fileNameExpression = parser.parseExpression("payload.name");
```

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setFileNameExpression` is used only for the `GET` operation.

Try to use `setFileNameGenerator` instead. This one is exactly for `PUT`.

Comment: The javadocs leave something to be desired - I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3699).

Comment: Got it. I thought an expression could be used directly to generate the remote file name. As an equivalent of the xml config:
    remote-filename-generator-expression="payload.getName() + '_foo'". Thanks for clarifying.